# sqldf only returning one row, same query used in SQL

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

For some reason I'm only returning one row when it comes to R while at SQL Server, I'm returning the correct number of rows.
SQLDF:

```r
CustomerCodingChangesT <- sqldf("
        SELECT c.CustID as ID 
             , c.ReverseSupplier as Supplier
             , c.ReverseCustomerCode as Code
             , c.Name
             , c.Address
             , c.[From PostCode]
             , c.[From Outlet]
             , c.[From OutletName] 
             , o.FullAddress AS [From Address]
             , c.[To PostCode]
             , c.[To Outlet]
             , c.[To OutletName]
             , o1.FullAddress AS [To Address]
             , MAX(CAST(c.TotalUnits AS VARCHAR)) AS [Total Units]
             , '$'+MAX(CAST(c.TotalValue AS VARCHAR)) AS [Total Value]
             , '' AS Checked
             , c.CustRecActive as Active

        FROM CustomerCorrectionSummaryT AS c
        LEFT JOIN OutletMasterT AS o 
             ON  c.[From PostCode] = o.Postcode 
             AND c.[From Outlet] = o.Outlet 
        LEFT JOIN OutletMasterT AS o1 
             ON  c.[To PostCode] = o1.Postcode 
             AND c.[To Outlet] = o1.Outlet
        ORDER BY c.totalvalue DESC;")
```

SQL:

```sql
if object_id ('tempdb..#CustomerCodingChanges') is not null drop table #CustomerCodingChanges

SELECT c.CustID as ID
     , c.ReverseSupplier as Supplier
     , c.ReverseCustomerCode as Code
     , c.Name
     , c.Address
     , c.[From Postcode]
     , c.[From Outlet]
     , c.[From OutletName]
     , o.FullAddress AS [From Address]
     , c.[To Postcode]
     , c.[To Outlet]
     , c.[To OutletName]
     , o1.FullAddress AS [To Address]
     , CAST(c.TotalUnits AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Total Units]
     , '$'+CAST(c.TotalValue AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Total Value]
     , '' AS Checked 
     , c.CustRecActive as Active

INTO #CustomerCodingChanges
FROM #CustomerCorrectionSummary AS c
LEFT JOIN ndf_061.IRGMaster.dbo.OutletMaster AS o 
     ON  c.[From Postcode] = o.postcode 
     AND c.[From Outlet] = o.outlet
LEFT JOIN ndf_061.IRGMaster.dbo.OutletMaster AS o1 
     ON  c.[To Postcode] = o1.postcode 
     AND c.[To Outlet] = o1.outlet
ORDER BY c.totalvalue DESC;
```

Both dataframes for `CustomerCorrectionSummaryT` and `OutletMasterT` have the same number of results in R and in SQL Server so I don't know why it won't also show the same number of results in R versus in SQL Server. In SQL Server query returns 22 rows while in R I'm only getting one row which both are correct. R's sqldf just doesn't show all of it. I'm thinking it has something to do with my `left join` function but I don't really know. Let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you carefully review, those two queries are not the same. Notably, you call an aggregate in first query, `MAX`, that you do not call in second query. Hence, first query is an aggregate query which collapses unit-level rows by various groupings returning aggregates (`SUM`, `COUNT`, `AVG` , `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.) on specified columns.

Additionally, because you do not include a `GROUP BY` clause, in standard ANSI SQL the first query should have raised an error. Unfortunately for newcomers of SQL some dialects like SQLite and MySQL allow such syntax. And R's `sqldf` runs SQLite by default. In fact, had you run that first query in SQL Server, it would err out since you run an incorrect aggregate query by not included non-aggregated columns in `GROUP BY` clause though they are specified in `SELECT` clause.

Looking closely, you appear to be trying to translate the below expression in SQL Server

```sql
CAST(c.TotalUnits AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Total Units]
```

which is not the same as this attempted line in first query:

```sql
MAX(CAST(c.TotalUnits AS VARCHAR)) AS [Total Units]
```

SQLite actually does not maintain a [maximum length in VARCHAR](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9)  types. So simply keep the original line without aggregation or size limit:

```sql
CAST(c.TotalUnits AS VARCHAR) AS [Total Units]
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you for this! I was losing hope that no one would answer this when it was downvoted to -1. I'm just new in stackoverflow and I really tried my best to look for similar issues that caused my error but I guess I didnt look at the ```MAX``` functionality very well. Thank you again!

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Happy coding!